# How to use getters and setters in an Abstract Class

Tags: java, oop, abstract-class

I have an abstract class `Customer`.  It's a very simple class, only setting 5 `string` variables as well as 5 `static int` variables. Better to show what I mean by this:

As a disclaimer I made the code as simple as possible, I have more logic involved in my abstract class that doesn't pertain to the question.

---

#### Abstract Class

```
public abstract class Customer {
     private String Name, Address, Phone, Email, Company;
     public static final int NAME = 0, ADDRESS = 1, PHONE = 2, EMAIL = 3, COMPANY = 4;

     public Customer(String Name, String Address, String Phone, String Email, String Company) {
         setValues(Name, Address, Phone, Email, Company);
     }

     private void setValues(String Name, String Address, String Phone, String Email, String Company) {
         setName(Name);
         setAddress(Address);
         setPhone(Phone);
         setEmail(Email);
         setCompany(Company);
     }
//declare public getters and setters methods below
}
```

My question is as follows:

I have a `class` that `extends` this `abstract class` called `Customer` (different package).  If I set up the `constructor` in this `class` as such:

---

#### Object Class

```
public class Customer extends Main.Customer {
     private String Name, Address, Phone, Email, Company;

     public Customer(String Name, String Address, String Phone, String Email, String Company) {
         super(Name, Address, Phone, Email, Company);
     }    
}
```

---

Does this set my `String` variables as to whatever I pass through the constructor?  As in when I `instantiate` this `class` as an `object`, how would I be able to 'get' a variable from it?
For example: (Assume `String1 -String5` are `strings` of some sort)

```
public class Random {
private Customer customer = new Customer(String1, String2, String3, String4, String5);

}
```

How would I then call the object later on in the class to return a `string` (of any single variable).  As in if my `abstract class` wasn't `abstract` but the main `class` I was using to `instantiate` as an `object`, I'd get the variable like so:  `String name = customer.getName();`

---

### TL;DR:

Just unsure how to get `variables` from an `object` `extending` an `abstract class`.

Comment: Just a plain getter in the abstract class doesn't work?

Comment: BTW -- if you want to set a lot of variables when a class is constructed, you might consider using a fluent interface or a builder pattern.

Comment: Whats the benefit of having two versions of `Customer` (which is confusing), they're presenting the same information...(same properties)

Comment: @ccleve Firstly, I'm asking how I 'call' the getter/setter of an abstract class when it's subclass is instantiated as an object.  Is it the same as calling the object with the method?  I have no getters/setters in my subclass.

Secondly it's how I code personally, I can follow this style a lot easier.  Variables declared first, then the constructer, then the getters/setters, then any other methods.  Just my personal likes

Comment: How come `String name = customer.getName();` doesn't work?  You indicated that the get functions in the abstract class were public: `//declare public getters and setters methods below`. Your subclass would get those public methods automatically.

Comment: That's what I was asking, so that's all I have to do, thanks!

Comment: @MadProgrammer I can't instantiate an abstract class.  I did rename the class though, sub-class I mean.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Drop the variables from your subclass so they don't shadow the variables with the same name in the parent class.

```
//sub class
public class Customer extends Main.Customer {
 //DROP THESE private String Name, Address, Phone, Email, Company;

    public Customer(String Name, String Address, String Phone, String Email, String Company) {
        super(Name, Address, Phone, Email, Company);
     }    
}
```

And add getters to your parent class:

```
//parent class
public abstract class Customer {
 private String Name, Address, Phone, Email, Company;
 public static final int NAME = 0, ADDRESS = 1, PHONE = 2, EMAIL = 3, COMPANY = 4;

 public Customer(String Name, String Address, String Phone, String Email, String Company) {
     setValues(Name, Address, Phone, Email, Company);
 }

 private void setValues(String Name, String Address, String Phone, String Email, String Company) {
     setName(Name);
     setAddress(Address);
     setPhone(Phone);
     setEmail(Email);
     setCompany(Company);
 }

 public String getName() {
   return Name;
 }

 public String getAddress() {
   return Address;
 }

 //etc....

}
```

Also, I really recommend using different names for your parent and subclass to avoid confusion.

Comment: Thank you all I was looking for.  I have the getters/setters publicly declared already, just didn't post them to save space.

Comment: Glad to help.  If you think this answer is the best, then please accept it by clicking the check mark.

Answer (score 3):

Some considerations before start:

- In java by code-convention variables starts with lower-case. It will help code readability for people including you.
- Don't have two classes with the same name, is very confusing. You can call it for example `ACustomer` or `AbstractCustomer` and the other one `Customer` or `SomethingCustomer`
- It isn't `Object class` it's `Concrete Class` a class that you can have instances of it.
- As Customer inherits ACustomer you don't have to define again the `ACustomer` fields, Customer already has them. If you do you are *hiding* those from parent.

---

```
public class Customer extends ACustomer {

         public Customer(String name, String address, String phone, String email, String company) {
             super(name, address, phone, email, company);
         }    
    }
```

- You are calling an overrideable method inside the constructor take care about that, cause if `setXXX` is override then perhaps you could have a `NullPointerException`.
- For your question in how to get member you can define `getters`.

---

```
public abstract class ACostumer{
      private String name;


     public String getName() {
       return name;
     }

 }
```

Then in client code:

```
ACustomer customer = new Customer(...);
customer.getName();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your subclass is overshadowing the private properties of the abstract class.

```
public abstract class Customer {
    private String Name, Address, Phone, Email, Company;

public class Customer extends Main.Customer {
    private String Name, Address, Phone, Email, Company;
```

so any get methods in your abstract class of the form

```
public String getName() {
    return Name;
}
```

would return the never initialized variable name in the subclass.  Whereas, when you call `super(...)`, the set functions there would set the variables of the abstract class.

So you are setting one set of variables, but reading another set of variables that were never initialized.